# Animations on child elements don't fire :leave if the host component is changed to *ngIf="false"

Tags: angular

I am trying to create an enter/leave animation for a slide menu. The menu is opened with an *ngIf ( because I require ngOnInt )

Externally:

```
<app-slide-menu *ngIf="isOpen"></app-slide-menu>
```

Internally:

```
<div class="dark-overlay" [@fadeinout] ></div>
<nav class="menu" [@slideinout] >
    <a>Link</a>
    <a>Link</a>
    <a>Link</a>
    <a>Link</a>
</nav>
```

When `isOpen` is changed externally, the `:enter` animations for the child elements of `app-slide-menu` work, however, the `:leave` animations don't when `isOpen = false`.

It seems like the `*ngIf` of the parent isn't delayed for the child animations/they don't even know they are dieing.

Should I do something like pass in `isOpen: boolean` via `@Input()` and apply it to the children?

Maybe even add an animation to the `HostBinding` that does nothing but delays it's `*ngIf`?

Comment: Can you have  ap lunker to replicate this issue

Answer (score 4):

[this comment](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/15798#issuecomment-305934289) from Matsko worked for me.

#### Here is the gist of it:

Angular 4 introduced a few new animation features. The ones that help to make :leave animation work on child elements are `query` and `animateChild`.

**Here is Matsko's example:**

```
@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `
    <div>
      <h2>Hello {{name}}</h2>
      <button (click)="toggle()">Toggle</button>
      <div *ngIf="show" @ngIfAnimation>
        <h3 @easeInOut>I'm inside ngIf</h3>
      </div>
    </div>
  `,
animations: [
  trigger('ngIfAnimation', [
    transition(':enter, :leave', [
      query('@*', animateChild())
    ])
  ])
  //...
]
})
class App {...}
```

Comment: Perfect when animation is on an external-defined child component :) Thanks so much :))

Answer (score 1):

> Hi, I make small example:

https://embed.plnkr.co/RDL4yuex2Q7gGbHlcLsQ/

Definition of transition for showup:

```
transition('void => *', [...
```

And definition of transition for hide:

```
transition('* => void', [...
```

**'void'** : This state is reserved by Angular. void state means element is not the part of application anymore. void state example is that when ngIf expression value is false and that element is no more in DOM.

**'*'** : This is the default state. This is a state which has not been declared within the trigger function. * state is used for dynamic start and ending state in animation.